# You don't have required permission to access this profile using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

While I creating ad by `facebook graph api` I got an error like below

```py
{"error_user_msg": "You don't have required permission to access this profile", "code": 10, "type": "OAuthException", "message": "Application does not have permission for this action", "fbtrace_id": "BTycRY47T1m", "error_user_title": "No permission to access this profile", "error_subcode": 1341012, "is_transient": false}, {"error_user_msg": "You don't have required permission to access this profile", "code": 10, "type": "OAuthException", "message": "Application does not have permission for this action", "fbtrace_id": "ElyXM7OX//O", "error_user_title": "No permission to access this profile", "error_subcode": 1341012, "is_transient": false}]
```

the page is promoted, and user's task is  `['ADVERTISE', 'ANALYZE']` but it always fail to create an ad?

Can you tell me the reason of this error? great thanks..

> update:

part of main codes:

```py
...
   elif params.objective=="PRODUCT_CATALOG_SALES":
                    # https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/ads-management/?translation#adtemplate
                    cre["object_story_spec"]={
                        "page_id":params.page_id,
                        "template_data":{
                            "call_to_action":{
                                "type":c["type"]
                            },
                            "name":c["link_text"],
                            "description":c["description"],
                            "link":c["link"],
                            "message":c["message"]
                        }
                    }
                    cre["product_set_id"]=params.product_set_id
                ad={
                    "name":"Ad_{}_{}".format(params.name,i+1),
                    "creative":json.dumps(cre),
                    "status":"PAUSED"
                }
                ads.append(ad)
...

# then use batch request, and user token to create some ads at one time.
```

Using `user token` to create ad in a batch way

Comment: how do you authorize? are you using a page token? did you debug the token? what´s your code?

Comment: @luschn thanks for your replying sir, I 've updated more details above